# Separating Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, include

I am wondering how javascripts get included in a jsp - can we put any code which the **jsp** will recognize and not just javascript code only in the .js file?

I have some common javascript code which needs to get executed on different pages, so I decided to place it in its own separate .js file and include it on all jsps which call that function.

The js function now refers to a key from a properties file and some other non-javascript code:

```
function openPrivacyStmntWindow(){
var url = <h:outputText escape="false" value="\"#{urls.url_privacyStatement}\";" />
newwindow=window.open(url,'Terms','height=600,width=800,left=300,top=100,scrollbars=1');
newwindow.focus();
return false;
```

}

This function worked just fine when it was included in the jsp itself. Now that I have separated it into its own file it doesnt, do I need to include the properties bundle in this file.

The  value="\"#{urls.url_privacyStatement}\";"   is referring to a bundle called "urls" which has a key called "url_privacyStatement"

Also in Line 1 `var url = <h:outputText escape="false" value="\"#{urls.url_privacyStatement}\";" />`
the `<h:outputText escape="false" ... />` will it cause any issues?

Thanks.

Comment: You should escape anything you put in a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use custom tags in your `js` files. But you can extract this to a separate `jsp` page and include it in all the pages. You can also set the `contentType` for that jsp to be `text/javascript`.

Comment: Re `contentType`: can and *really should*.

Comment: This works beautifully! I placed my js function in a jsp page with content only javascript. A very smart way of getting around the problem, many thanks. :-)